# I'm trying to remove ALL matching values by comparing list a to list b in python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a problem that requires me to remove all values from list a that are present in list b. for example `list_a = [1,2,3]` and `list_b = [1,2]`. The element that isn't matching should be returned in a new_array.

Here is my current code:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    
    new_array = []
    
    for val in a:
        if not b:
            new_array  = a
            return new_array
        
        if val in b:
            
            new_array = list(filter (lambda a: a != val, a))
            
    return new_array
```

The problem I'm currently running into is I have an edge case that has list_a as  [1,2,3] and list_b as [1,2]. This should return a new_array of [3] however it's not. Can anyone help me find the flow in my solution?

Comment: Hint: in the second turn through the `for` loop (i.e, when `val` is 2), what is the value of `a`? What is the input to `filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first iteration of `for val in a:`, `val` is 1.  `if val in b` is true, and therefore `new_array` is created as a new list containing all elements in `a` that are not equal to 1.

On the second iteration of `for val in a:`, `val` is 2.  `if val in b` is true, and therefore `new_array` is recreated as a new list containing all elements in `a` that are not equal to 2.

On the third iteration of `for val in a:`, `val` is 3.  `if val in b` is false, and therefore `new_array` is not modified.

Then the loop ends, and `new_array` is returned.

This is a very roundabout way to do what you want.  Why not just assign `new_array = [x for x in a if x not in b]` and be done with it?

Comment: thanks for the great answer, can I ask when you write x there in the beginning when you write x for x what is the first x doing?

Comment: @aroe It's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).